# I want to add value to an array on click in react

Tags: arrays, reactjs, onclick

I want to add the value to an array in state `onClick` event in React.

So far with the `onSelectRooms` function, I can get the value with e.target.id but It doesn't append the value to the array `selectedRooms` that's on state.

```
    onSelectRooms = (e) => {

        const newItem = e.target.id; 

        this.setState({
            selectedRooms: [...this.state.selectedRooms, newItem]}); 
    }
```

```
export default class ExportReportRoomSelectionModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const roomOrder = configContext.value.roomOrder;


        this.state = {
            rooms: roomOrder,
            selectedRooms: [],
        };


        this.onSelectRooms = this.onSelectRooms.bind(this);

    }

    onSelectRooms = (e) => {

        const newItem = e.target.id; 

        this.setState({
            selectedRooms: [...this.state.selectedRooms, newItem]}); 
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <Modal>
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>Title</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <p>Number of rooms: {this.state.rooms.length}</p>
                    <p>Rooms:</p>

                    <Grid fluid={true}> 
                        <Row className="show-grid">
                            { this.state.rooms.map((name, i ) => 

                                <Col key={i}>
                                    <Panel onClick={this.onSelectRooms}>  
                                        <Panel.Heading id={name}> 
                                            {name}                               
                                        </Panel.Heading>
                                    </Panel> 
                                </Col>
                            )}
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>

                </Modal.Body>

            </Modal>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Input field and define a name for this input field.

And collect data from this input field by
 
 this.refs.inputFieldName.value

 and
 push this inside your declared array variable.
 
Below Git Project link with full crud and Documentation. 
Try it

https://gitlab.com/ripon52/reactcrud

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `index` of clicked room to `onSelectRooms` function.

```
export default class ExportReportRoomSelectionModal extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const roomOrder = configContext.value.roomOrder;


        this.state = {
            rooms: roomOrder,
            selectedRooms: [],
        };

    }

    onSelectRooms = (e, index) => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            selectedRooms: [...prevState.selectedRooms, index]
        })); 
    }


    render() {

        return (
            <Modal>
                <Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Title>Title</Modal.Title>
                </Modal.Header>
                <Modal.Body>
                    <p>Number of rooms: {this.state.rooms.length}</p>
                    <p>Rooms:</p>

                    <Grid fluid={true}> 
                        <Row className="show-grid">
                            { this.state.rooms.map((name, i ) => 

                                <Col key={i}>
                                    <Panel onClick={() => this.onSelectRooms(i)}>  
                                        <Panel.Heading id={name}> 
                                            {name}                               
                                        </Panel.Heading>
                                    </Panel> 
                                </Col>
                            )}
                        </Row>
                    </Grid>

                </Modal.Body>

            </Modal>);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
const joined = this.state.selectedRooms.concat(newItem);
this.setState({ selectedRooms: joined })
```

Answer (score 0):

change onSelectRooms() with below code and check

```
    onSelectRooms = (e) => {
        const newItem = e.target.id; 
        let roomArray = this.state.selectedRooms;
        roomArray.push(newItem);                   //add value in local array
        this.setState({selectedRooms: roomArray}); //replace selectedRooms with local arry
    }
```

enjoy !